# Excel Chart: Using the input from user into the SeriesCollection

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a program where the user will input the name of the sheet that they want. After that, the program will create a new sheet and new chart with the name that user give. The code is shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim test_num As Variant
'Dim sheetName As Variant

Sub NewWSName()

test_num = InputBox("Enter the test number: (Ex: T1 for Test #1)", "Test Number")
If test_num <> "" Then
   Sheets.Add.Name = test_num & " Data"
End If

End Sub

Sub NewChart()

If test_num <> "" Then
   Charts.Add.Name = test_num & " Basic Chart"
End If
End Sub

Sub basic_10()
'Add chart sheet and clear the content
NewChart
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear

'Set the chart type as 3D Column
ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DColumn

Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set NewWB = ActiveWorkbook

With NewWB
    thisWB.Sheets("Basic Chart").ChartArea.Copy
    NewWB.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Paste

    'NewWB.Charts(test_num & " Basic Chart").Activate
    'ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    'Here is the error start
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name "=' & test_num & ' Data'!$Q$12"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=' & test_num & ' Data'!$Q$13:$Q$44"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=' & test_num & ' Data'!$R$12"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & test_num & " Data!$R$13:$R$44"

End With
End Sub
```

On the `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name "=' & test_num & ' Data'!$Q$12"` is where i got the error. How can I use the input from user to assign the location where I want the data to be collected? I already try other things, but didn't work as well. I can't assign it as `Sheets(1)` or something like that because I cannot predict how many times the user want to collect the data. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in your Sub in place of `Sheets.Add.Name = test_num & " Data"`:

```
Dim w As Worksheet

Set w = Sheets.Add

w.Name = test_num & " Data"
```

You'll also need to do something similar for `Charts.Add.Name`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I got it now. I just have to change the part where `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name "=' & test_num & ' Data'!$Q$12"` to `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets(1).Range("$Q$12")`